# How is the TRUNCATE command in Oracle able to retrieve the structure of a table after dropping it?

Tags: oracle

The SQL command TRUNCATE in Oracle is faster than than `DELETE FROM table;` in that the TRUNATE comand first drops the specified table in it's entirely and then creates a new table with same structure (clarification may require in case I may be **wrong**). Since TRUNCATE is a part of DDL it implicitly issues COMMIT before being executed and after the completion of execution. If such is a case then, the table that is dropped by the TRUNCATE command is lost permanently with it's entire structure in the data dictionary. In such a scenario, how is the TRUNCATE command able to drop first the table and recreate the same with the same structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thought a truncate (amoungst other things) simply reset the High Water Mark.

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/statements_10007.htm#SQLRF01707

however in
http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2816964500346433991

It is clear that the data segment changes after a truncate.

Comment: The data segment does indded change, but only if it has been modified since table creation. A newly created (or truncated) table that has had no inserts into it (including ones that were immediately rolled back) will not have a new data segment assigned. I think that it's better to explain a truncate as the assignment of a new data segment myself.#

Answer (score 7):

*(Note that I work for Sybase in SQL Anywhere engineering and my answer comes from my knowledge of how `truncate` is implemented there, but I imagine it's similar in Oracle as well.)*

I don't believe the table is actually dropped and re-created; the contents are simply thrown away. This is much faster than `delete from <table>` because no triggers need to be executed, and rather than deleting a row at a time (both from the table and the indexes), the server can simply throw away **all** pages that contain rows for that table and any indexes.